# Why smppcxx sample_app isn't working and returns "SMPP error: Invalid command_length" and crashes?

Tags: sms, smpp

I took sample_app from smppcxx library and changed the settings to:

```
const std::string ipaddr = "194.228.174.1";
const Smpp::Uint16 port = 9111;
const Smpp::SystemId sysid("MaxiTipSMPP");
const Smpp::Password pass(<actual_password>);
const Smpp::SystemType systype("");
const Smpp::Uint8 infver = 0x34;
const Smpp::ServiceType servtype("");
const Smpp::Address srcaddr("234567");
const Smpp::Address dstaddr("420606752839");
const std::string msgtext = "Hello smsc";
```

The code called is:

```
    Socket sd;
    sd.connect(ipaddr.c_str(), port);
    send_bind(sd);
    read_bind_resp(sd);
    //send_enquire_link(sd);
    //read_enquire_link_resp(sd);
    send_submit_sm(sd);
    read_submit_sm_resp(sd);
    Smpp::Uint32 seqnum = read_deliver_sm(sd);
    send_deliver_sm_resp(sd, seqnum);
    //send_data_sm(sd);
    //read_data_sm_resp(sd);
    //seqnum = read_deliver_sm(sd);
    //send_deliver_sm_resp(sd, seqnum);
    send_unbind(sd);
    read_unbind_resp(sd);
```

and the problem happens in read_submit_sm_resp(sd) (or in read_enquire_link_resp(sd) if uncommented):

```
    Buffer buf;
    buf = read_smpp_pdu(sd, buf);
    std::cout << "\nRead a submit sm resp\n";
    Smpp::hex_dump(&buf[0], buf.size(), std::cout);
    Smpp::SubmitSmResp pdu;
    std::cout << "read_submit_sm_resp buf.size() is " << buf.size() << std::endl;
    pdu.decode(&buf[0]);
    std::string sid = pdu.message_id();
    printf("response message_id: \"%s\"\n", sid.c_str());
```

on line

```
    pdu.decode(&buf[0]);
```

, why? The application crashes. I expected the code to work as is, but it just doesn't.

There is the output:

```
Sending a bind transceiver
00 00 00 2a 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01    ...*............
4d 61 78 69 54 69 70 53 4d 50 50 00                MaxiTipSMPP.password

Read a bind response
00 00 00 15 80 00 00 09 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01    ................
53 4d 53 43 00                                     SMSC.
read_bind_resp buf.size() is 21
response system_id: "SMSC"

Sending a submit sm
00 00 00 3d 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01    ...=............
00 00 00 32 33 34 35 36 37 00 01 01 34 32 30 36    ...234567...4206
30 36 37 35 32 38 33 39 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00    06752839........
00 00 0a 48 65 6c 6c 6f 20 73 6d 73 63             ...Hello smsc

Read a submit sm resp
00 00 00 a4 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01    ................
00 01 01 39 39 39 30 33 30 00 01 01 34 32 30 36    ...999030...4206
30 36 37 35 32 38 33 39 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00    06752839........
00 00 47 69 64 3a 66 62 32 37 37 66 62 34 33 66    ..Gid:fb277fb43f
63 31 34 36 66 30 39 61 39 31 37 37 32 63 37 63    c146f09a91772c7c
31 33 64 65 35 62 20 64 6f 6e 65 20 64 61 74 65    13de5b done date
3a 31 37 30 32 30 36 30 35 30 37 30 34 20 73 74    :170206050704 st
61 74 3a 55 4e 44 45 4c 49 56 00 1e 00 21 66 62    at:UNDELIV...!fb
32 37 37 66 62 34 33 66 63 31 34 36 66 30 39 61    277fb43fc146f09a
39 31 37 37 32 63 37 63 31 33 64 65 35 62 00 04    91772c7c13de5b..
27 00 01 05                                        '...
read_submit_sm_resp buf.size() is 164
SMPP error: Invalid command_length
```

I added an output and it tells that size is 164 and I see 164 bytes and in bind response, which works without problems, there is size 21 and I see 21 bytes, should I fix the decode function somehow?

```
Smpp::SubmitSmResp::decode(const Smpp::Uint8* buff)
{
    Response::decode(buff);

    Smpp::Uint32 len = Response::command_length();
    Smpp::Uint32 offset = 16;
    const char* err = "Bad length in submit_sm_resp";
    if(len < offset)
        throw Error(err);

    const Smpp::Char* sptr = reinterpret_cast<const Smpp::Char*>(buff);
    message_id_ = &sptr[offset];
    offset += message_id_.length() + 1;

    if(len < offset)
        throw Error(err);

    Header::decode_tlvs(buff + offset, len - offset);
}
```

I still think that the library should work as is, so I guess that maybe I should change some setting or something. Did anyone have the same problem? Any idea what to do? The only thing I want is to send smses, about max 100 a day...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it.

1) Have only 1 open connection instead of opening a new connection for every sms to send. Provider banned me, because of too many connection openings.

2) The flow isn't send->read->send->read->.., but reading of the responses should be done asynchronously and so the client must parse the responses to understand, what type of response was received.

3) The connection should be maintained with send_enquire_link.

I guess that programming this gateway for sending smses was far over the scope of 1 manday for a person like me that didn't know anything about smpp. I finished the task in about 3 days with quite a lot of work overnight. Why do I add that? Because the main problem was my approach because of the assigned time => I thought that there should be a simple solution for 1 manday task...